# How to get all ldap groups for a user

Tags: ldap

I have no direct access to LDAP, but I am a user in LDAP and can make queries using ldapsearch.  How can I query LDAP to get all LDAP groups for a particular user?  Also is there an easy way to get LDAP group names from the gid attribute?  I

Comment: This depends on the used LDAP. ActiveDirectory has bi-directional `memberOf`-style group memberships, while OpenLDAP has regular `member`-style group memberships. The basic difference: in one (`member`) case you'll have to query the groups for their members and then filter those out, where the desired user is a member.  The other: the user has a `memberOf` attribute, which lists all groups the user is a member of.

Comment: This is Sun LDAP

Comment: relevant note from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722889/ -- "You can interrogate the root DN of any LDAP server to find out whether it supports the feature."